# How can I customize/design the View Article page

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, articles, overrides, template-override

I want to customize and design the view page for articles   I also want to add related articles module and move next and previous articles on the article page.

How can I do that?

Please advise...

Comment: So what's your actual question here?

Comment: I want to customize the article page, that's it how can i do that? I searched the net for similar cases but I couldn't find

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to change the structure/styling for an Article view, you need to create a Template Override, all of which is explained here:

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

Template overrides allow us to edit the view of an extension without editing the core file which may get overridden in an update.

So once you have you override done, you can now edit:

> ROOT/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_content/article/default.php

Hope this helps

Comment: thanx, I want to change the appearance of the article page. Does override help me? Sorry if this seems simple but I'm new to Joomla 3.3.6

Comment: Yes, Once you've created your article, you can edit the HTML layout in file given in my answer.